# AngularJS web api call - can't find get method on controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I cannot for the life of me understand why this isn't working.

I have a simple ASP.Net MVC Web API controller, with 2 get methods. I have an AngularJS service with 2 corresponding functions. The GetAllRisks works perfectly well. However, the GetRiskByID comes back with an error saying "No HTTP request was found that matches the request "http://localhost:49376/api/RiskApi/GetRiskByID/6" and "No action can be found on the RiskApi controller that matches the request."

The URL is being passed correctly. I have tried various options for the API routing but can't get anywhere. I am sure I am missing something simple but can't see it.

I would really appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks,

Ash

**RiskApiController**

```
public class RiskApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRiskDataService _riskDataService;

    public RiskApiController(IRiskDataService riskDataService)
    {
        _riskDataService = riskDataService;
    }

    // GET api/RiskApi
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<IRisk> GetAllRisks()
    {
        return _riskDataService.GetAllRisks().Take(20);
    }

    // GET api/RiskApi/5
    [HttpGet]
    public IRisk GetRiskByID(int riskID)
    {
        IRisk risk = _riskDataService.GetRiskByID(riskID);
        if (risk == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return risk;
    }
}
```

**service.js**

```
app.service('OpenBoxExtraService', function ($http) {

//Get All Risks
this.getAllRisks = function () {
    return $http.get("/api/RiskApi/GetAllRisks");
}

//Get Single Risk by ID
this.getRisk = function (riskID) {
    var url = "/api/RiskApi/GetRiskByID/" + riskID;
    return $http.get(url);
}
});
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: [drive by...you might have another layer of problems, but this stood out to me] You can't give the HttpRouteCollection multiple routes with the same name.  Change your second route's name value from 'DefaultApi' to "Foo" and it might work.

Comment: well....your optional routeParameters are going to be in conflict.  Which route should be chosen if you provide `/api/RiskApi/foo`? It would match the api/{controller}/{id} as well as the api/{controller}/{action}/{id} route since you've got {id} optional on both. The router won't be able to tell if foo is an {id} or an {action} value. It naturally won't be able to send "foo" in as an int for the id, but I'm not sure if the router is intelligent enough to infer that the {action} based route is the one you want. I think it will just fail to route.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by routes with the same name as they have different names (ActionRoute and DeafultApi). I take your point about the conflicts, but thought that would manifest itself in possibly choosing the wrong route, rather than not finding a route at all. I will look into the RoutingAttributes. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: ...oh wow. I totally read both of those Route names as "DefaultApi" when I wrote the comment.

Comment: ...so, is this new dev?  It doesn't really make sense to build this on first-gen Web API and MVC 4 unless you're maintaining an existing first-gen Web API product.  Why did you decide to anchor your system down to obsolete technology? Is it only because you're wanting to use VS2010?

Comment: Yes new dev. It's what I am stuck with in my office at the moment. I am praying we get to upgrade early next year.

Comment: Just to make sure; you are able to access `/api/RiskApi/GetAllRisks`?

Comment: @sjokkogutten yes I am. That part works fine.

Comment: @TheDumbRadish I think Danny caught your problem.  Your "id" parameter names don't match between your route config and your controller method.  You call it `{id}` in the route, but `riskID` in the method.  These need to match.

Comment: Have you tried to simply uncomment one of the entries in `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`? I think you only need one of those

Comment: @sjokkogutten I was assuming that the separate routes served a purpose and that he was desiring an RPC-style calling pattern; not the style I prefer, but "whatever floats your boat."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your WebApiConfig class to:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And change your param: `riskID` to `id`.

```
// GET: api/RiskApi/GetRiskByID/5
[HttpGet]
public IRisk GetRiskByID(int id)
{
    IRisk risk = _riskDataService.GetRiskByID(id);
    if (risk == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return risk;
}
```

Then, you could use:

```
// GET: api/RiskApi/GetAllRisks
// GET: api/RiskApi/GetRiskByID/5
```

Comment: That is my first route already. And I am using the URL you suggested in my service.

Comment: Yeah, but it's about your WebApiConfig class.

Comment: Tried that but it resulted in the same error (as I thought it might as it was already my first route). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm, did you try changing your param: `riskID` to `id`?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez lol...that's gonna be it.  switch `riskID` to `id` in your controller method or change `id` to `riskID` in your route configuration.

Comment: In the Controller method. Because, your WebApiConfig class will work like a WebApi's template config.

Comment: Bloody hell!! Well done Danny. I knew it would be something so ridiculous. Thank you so much. Ash

Answer (score 0):

...try junking your config's `HttpRoute` Mapping and introduce the route mapping with Attributes.

Since this is first-gen Web API, you'll need to pull in the **AttributeRouting.WebAPI** NuGet package, and you'll likely want to refer [here(strathweb)](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/) for straightforward guidance on how to implement.

Note that you have a mapping problem in your current implementation on your `{id}` parameter: you declare it to be id in the route configuration, but then you identify it as `riskID` inside the controller's method; these need to match. Switch your controller's method to have its incoming routeParameter be named `id`. You could optionally switch your config to declare the `{riskID}` parameter in your routes, but that would couple your global configuration to the semantics of a specific controller and you'd likely need to implement more routing constraints to have other controllers not named "Risk" make sense.

```
public class RiskApiController : ApiController
{
   private readonly IRiskDataService _riskDataService;

   public RiskApiController(IRiskDataService riskDataService)
   {
       _riskDataService = riskDataService;
   }

   // GET api/RiskApi
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/RiskApi")]
   public IEnumerable<IRisk> GetAllRisks()
   {
       return _riskDataService.GetAllRisks().Take(20);
   }

   // GET api/RiskApi/5
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/RiskApi/{id}")]
   public IRisk GetRiskByID(int id)
   {
       IRisk risk = _riskDataService.GetRiskByID(id);
       if (risk == null)
       {
           throw new    HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
       }
       return risk;
   }
}
```

Comment: (I was wondering why you were fully qualifying this as "ASP.NET MVC Web API" ...I didn't see your tag) It works by default with Web API 2. It won't work by default in "pre-2", but you can make it work with Nuget packages.  http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @TheDumbRadish what are you hosting in? ...IIS? ...Console?

Comment: IIS. Using my local machine as in the early stages of development at the moment.